# Table data export with identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I export this HTML table data in a way, that the exported data look exactly as the initial data.

The array `data[]` is the source for the table below. The button `dataToArray` exports this HTML table data back to an array. I struggle with the format as I need the data identifier, in the array, too.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery import-->
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #myTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #myTable td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #delRow {
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <th>
           Property 
        </th>
        <th>
            Value
        </th>
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="dataToArray">dataToArray</button>

    <script>
        data = [
            {
                "property": "animal",
                "value": "dog"
            },
            {
                "property": "car",
                "value": "audi"
            },
            {
                "property": "snacks",
                "value": "chips"
            }
        ]


        //populate table
        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")
        
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var row =   `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].property}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].value}</td>
                        </tr>`

            myTable.innerHTML += row   
        }

        //get table data
        var dataToArray = document.getElementById("dataToArray")

        dataToArray.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.clear()
            console.log("data before export:")
            console.log(data)

            var exportData = []
            $("table#myTable tr").each(function() {
                var rowDataArray = []
                var actualData = $(this).find("td");
                if (actualData.length > 0) {
                    actualData.each(function() {
                        rowDataArray.push($(this).text());
                    });
                exportData.push(rowDataArray)
                };
            })
            console.log("data after export:")
            console.log(exportData)
        })



    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define `rowDataArray` as new `Object`

I change your code only at this part:

```
 var exportData = []
            $("table#myTable tr").each(function() {
                var rowDataArray = []
                var actualData = $(this).find("td");
                if (actualData.length > 0) {
                    actualData.each(function() {
                        rowDataArray.push($(this).text());
                    });
                exportData.push(rowDataArray)
                };
            })
```

and change it with:

```
var exportData = []
        $("table#myTable tr").each(function() {
            var rowDataObject= new Object;
            var actualData = $(this).find("td");
            if (actualData.length > 0) {
                rowDataObject.property = actualData[0].innerText;
                rowDataObject.value= actualData[1].innerText;
                exportData.push(rowDataObject)
            };
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Table Test</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <!-- jquery import-->
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #myTable {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #myTable td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #delRow {
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <th>
           Property 
        </th>
        <th>
            Value
        </th>
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="dataToArray">dataToArray</button>

    <script>
        data = [
            {
                "property": "animal",
                "value": "dog"
            },
            {
                "property": "car",
                "value": "audi"
            },
            {
                "property": "snacks",
                "value": "chips"
            }
        ]


        //populate table
        var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")
        
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var row =   `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].property}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].value}</td>
                        </tr>`

            myTable.innerHTML += row   
        }

        //get table data
        var dataToArray = document.getElementById("dataToArray")

        dataToArray.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.clear()
            console.log("data before export:")
            console.log(data)

            var exportData = []
            $("table#myTable tr").each(function() {
                var rowDataObject= new Object;
                var actualData = $(this).find("td");
                if (actualData.length > 0) {
                    rowDataObject.property = actualData[0].innerText;
                    rowDataObject.value= actualData[1].innerText;
                    exportData.push(rowDataObject)
                };
            })
            console.log("data after export:")
            console.log(exportData)
        })



    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is dynamic way (works even for more than two headers without changing the export code):

First get all headers dynamically (not hard code) by this line:

```
var headers = $("table#myTable th").map(function () {
         return this.innerText;
     }).get();
```

And then in export time do like this:

```
 var object = {};
 headers.forEach((data, index) => {
     object[data] = actualData[index].innerText;
 })
 exportData.push(object)
```

```js
 data = [
     {
         "property": "animal",
         "value": "dog"
     },
     {
         "property": "car",
         "value": "audi"
     },
     {
         "property": "snacks",
         "value": "chips"
     }
 ]


 //populate table
 var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     var row = `<tr>
                         <td>${data[i].property}</td>
                         <td>${data[i].value}</td>
                     </tr>`

     myTable.innerHTML += row
 }

 //get table data
 var dataToArray = document.getElementById("dataToArray")

 dataToArray.addEventListener("click", function () {

     var headers = $("table#myTable th").map(function () {
         return this.innerText;
     }).get();
     console.clear()
     console.log("data before export:")
     console.log(data);

     var exportData = []
     $("table#myTable tr").each(function (e,i) {
         var rowDataArray = []
         var actualData = $(this).find("td");
         if (actualData.length > 0) {
             var object = {};
             headers.forEach((data, index) => {
                 object[data] = actualData[index].innerText;
             })
             exportData.push(object)
         };
     })
     console.log("data after export:")
     console.log(exportData)
 })
```

```css
#myTable {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

            #myTable td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 8px;
            }

        #delRow {
            width: auto;
            height: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
        <th>
            Property
        </th>
        <th>
            Value
        </th>
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
</table>

<button id="dataToArray">dataToArray</button>
```

Comment: @ICoded the answer works even you have more than two headers and there is no need to change the export code. because you dynamically get the headers not statically used `property` and `value`

Comment: @ICoded , This method is better and smarter than mine